# Change the last digit in a file

Tags: java, input, digit

So I want to write ten digits to a .txt file and when I run it, I want to place myself at the last digit so I can manually change the final digit. This is what I got so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    File file = new File("text.txt");

    if (!file.exists())
    {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    bw.write(" " + Arrays.toString(a));
    bw.close();

    System.out.println("Done!");
```

What this basically does is write ten digits in the form of an int array to a .txt file. Now how would I go about allowing myself to change the last digit, in this case: 10 through user input?

Comment: what is the purpose of storing these in a file?  do users need to be able to look at the file and understand its contents?  what are your long term performance needs?  the answers to these questions affect the correct answer to your question

Comment: This is merely a task that will hopefully help me grasp how to be able to perform what I want to do. It is not a part of anything greater so the actual performance does not matter, entirely.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1**

Read everything into memory from the file.

```
StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

File file = new File("test.txt");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   contents.append(line);
}
```

**Step 2**

Adjust the data in memory.

```
// Let's assume each day is split by a space
String[] numbers = contents.toString().split(" ");

numbers[numbers.length - 1] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(numbers[numbers.length - 1]) - 1);
```

**Step 3**

Write everything back.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

for(String number : numbers)
{
    out.write(number);
}

out.close();
```

Comment: The streams should really be done using a try-with-resources rather than just closing them. i.e. try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos))) { ... }

Comment: I am having some difficulties with step 2 on adjusting the data. While I can choose the split to happen at 10 (last digit), I am not able to actually append or write anything else in there. It just becomes blank and it's probably due to the fact that I cannot seem to run 

   numbers[numbers.length - 1] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(numbers[numbers.length - 1]) - 1);

That part of the code gives me an error stating: "
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "]"

Comment: at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)"

Any help? When I remove that part of the code, the last digit is removed so some progress has been made and I thank you for it.

Comment: So my code assumes that your code is split by spaces. If it's not split by spaces, you're going to see some funny effects. I would also remove any `\n` characters from your data; they could be lingering and causing trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Chris's answer is probably the most straight forward.  However another possible way is using a `RandomAccessFile`.  This would be a good option if the file you are maintaining is very large.

```
 public class RAFExample {
   public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,123};
    File file = new File("text.txt");
    System.out.println("File located at:  " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    RAFExample re = new RAFExample();

    try {
        re.saveArray(file,values);
        System.out.println("Current File Contents:  " + re.getFileContents(file));
        re.updateFile(file,9);
        System.out.println("Current File Contents:  " + re.getFileContents(file));
        re.updateFile(file,2342352);
        System.out.println("Current File Contents:  " + re.getFileContents(file));
        re.updateFile(file,-1);
        System.out.println("Current File Contents:  " + re.getFileContents(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}

public void saveArray(File file, int[] values) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
    try{
        String toFile  = Arrays.toString(values);
        System.out.println("Writing the following string to the file: " + toFile);
        bw.write(toFile);
    }finally{
        bw.close();
    }
}

public void updateFile(File f, int value) throws IOException{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f,"rw");
    // Find the last space in the file
    final byte space = ' ';
    try{
        String s;
        if(raf.length() == 0){
            s = "[" + value + "]";
            raf.write(s.getBytes());
        }else{
            raf.seek(raf.length());
            int b = raf.read();
            while(raf.getFilePointer() - 2 > 0 && b != space){
                raf.seek(raf.getFilePointer() - 2);
                b = raf.read();
            }
            // now we are at the position to write the new value
            if(raf.getFilePointer() == 0){
                // We got to the beginning of the file,
                // which means there is 1 or 0 values
                s = "[" + value + "]";
            }else{
                s = String.valueOf(value);
            }
            raf.write(s.getBytes());
            raf.write(']'); // This follows the format of Arrays.toString(array)
            raf.setLength(raf.getFilePointer());
        }
    }finally{
        raf.close();
    }
}
private String getFileContents(File f){
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        while(reader.ready()){
            sb.append(reader.readLine());
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }finally{
        if(reader != null){
            try{reader.close();}catch (IOException ignore){}
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
 }
```

Comment: You mention that Chris' answer is the most straight forward one yet I cannot seem to make it function properly. The actual code itself does not display any error yet whenever I implement:

 numbers[numbers.length - 1] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(numbers[numbers.length - 1]) - 1);


I get an error upon compiling that states:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "]"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)


Why

Comment: @user3071133 I did not check it, but I would bet it's because there isn't any check for the ']' character which is at the end of the string when you call `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Comment: I was actually able to use try and catch the NumberFormatException.

But even by using what Chris wrote, specifically in Step 2 => I want to be able to modify wherever the split takes place (in this case at digit 10) by typing in something. As of now, 10 is completely gone as it gets removed but how do I go about appending anything in that same area? Could I perhaps implement scanner somehow? Here's the full code => http://pastebin.com/XNWpAbjU

Comment: @user3071133 First, the comment says you want to split on space, but you split on "10".  The problem is that you are not taking the format of `Arrays.toString()` into account.  It's fine that you are using it, but you have to account for the characters comma, open-bracket, close-bracket and space.  Just look at the String created by Arrays.toString.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate problems. The first is how to get your "input". The data you want the user to add. To do that the simplest way would be to take a command line paramater in the arguments and use that as the final character.

so after doing the bw.write but before bw.close do

```
for (String str: args) {
    bw.write(str);
}
```

If you need to really wait for input but stay on the command line (rather than through a GUI) then you need to read from System.in()

The second problem is how to actually write to the correct point in the file. That can be done as per Chris' answer by reading the whole existing file and then writing back appending or it could be done by opening the file, seeking to the correct point, and then making the change. There is a Random Access Files system in Java that would help with this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html

Comment: I'm reading around regarding command line paramaters and this is completely new territory for me. Could I possibly get any additional help on how I would actually target that last digit and modify it?